# Java Applet Caching

Tags: java, caching, applet

I have a applet, lets call it A.jar

In A.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF I reference B.jar with the following line:

Class-path: B.jar

**However, my problem is that only A.jar is being cached, even though B.jar is displayed in the Java Cache Viewer as seen below:**

[image]

All this is happening while I am using this line of code to do caching:

```
cache_archive = "A.jar,B.jar"
```

And my cache disk space is set to maximum! What could be going wrong?

Comment: 1) You've described a problem, but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).  What *is* your question? 2) What evidence do you have that `b.jar` is *not* being cached?  Note the console is designed to who the original location of the Jar when loading it from the local cache.  That is a security measure.

Comment: 1.) I have updated the question, although I though the problem statement would be obvious toward describing the question, as the problem IS the question.
2.) The evidence is that I have a very slow connection, and every time the applet opens, it loads about 1 min, when I just refresh the page after the first load, it is instant. So I want the initial start-up time as quick as the refresh time (Granted the version on the server remained the same since last run)